# Android: How to load a page into a WebView and then apply some custom css to it?

Tags: android, webview

I need to load a page into a webview and then apply some custom css to it. This page is not under my control, so I can't simply add a CSS include or inline CSS within the page itself.

Right now I'm just doing an HTTP get request, putting the contents into a String, prepending the string with my custom css (in style tags), and finally doing a loadDataWithBaseURL() on the string.

Is there a more elegant/efficient solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well using what is available in the [Webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), you have probably done the best that could be done.

However, if you really want to do it elegantly, get the source codes of WebView and all the classes it needs. Alter them to ultimately add the function `WebView.setCSS()` (for example)... It is doable but it needs some time.

Answer (score -1):

you can just try WebView.reload() just like :

```
                           if(first_loading){

                w.loadUrl(DisplayActiviyParam.sd_html); 
                first_loading = false;

            }else{

                w.reload();

            }
```

,what you need do is tu change your css file contents. Good lucky!